# Secure shared preference android

Tags: android, performance, encryption, android-preferences

In my app I have to save username,password,token,.. to reuse them. Initially I save this data in normal shared preferences but on rooted device it's easy read all preferences and I think that this isn't a good thing.

Now I'm trying to use SecurePreferences library ([this](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)) but if I initialize this preferences in this way:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = new SecurePreferences(context);
```

when I open an activity or in a fragment onCreateView the initialize often takes about 2-3 second (I tested it with TraceView) and this slow my activity or fragment opening.

There is a way to put SecurePreferences in a Singleton and instantiate it only one time in all my app?
Or there is another best method to save this data and hide them to all external application?

**UPDATE #1:**

I found this solution. To instantiate only one time the SecurePreferences you should create an App class that extends Application in this way:

```
public class App extends Application {


private static final String TAG = "secureprefsample";
protected static App instance;
private SecurePreferences mSecurePrefs;
private SecurePreferences mUserPrefs;
public App(){
    super();
    instance = this;
}
public static App get() {
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Single point for the app to get the secure prefs object
 * @return
 */

public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
    if(mSecurePrefs==null){
        mSecurePrefs = new SecurePreferences(this, "", "my_prefs.xml");
        SecurePreferences.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    }
    return mSecurePrefs;
}


/**
 * This is just an example of how you might want to create your own key with less iterations 1,000 rather than default 10,000. This makes it quicker but less secure.
 * @return
 */

public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences1000() {
    try {
        AesCbcWithIntegrity.SecretKeys myKey = AesCbcWithIntegrity.generateKeyFromPassword(Build.SERIAL,AesCbcWithIntegrity.generateSalt(),1000);
        SharedPreferences securePrefs1000 = new SecurePreferences(this, myKey, "my_prefs_1000.xml");
        return securePrefs1000;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create custom key for SecurePreferences", e);
    }
    return null;
}


public SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreferences() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

public SecurePreferences getUserPinBasedSharedPreferences(String password){
    if(mUserPrefs==null) {
        mUserPrefs = new SecurePreferences(this, password, "user_prefs.xml");
    }
    return mUserPrefs;
}

public boolean changeUserPrefPassword(String newPassword){
    if(mUserPrefs!=null){
        try {
            mUserPrefs.handlePasswordChange(newPassword, this);
            return true;
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during password change", e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And then you must get the SecurePreferences in your activity in this way:

```
SharedPreferences preferences =App.get().getSharedPreferences();
```

Comment: Did you see this: "By default the generated key is stored in the backing preferences file and so can be read and extracted by root user."  You're just adding one step to what an attacker needs to do to get the data unless the user unlocks it with a password.  As for your question, have you tried creating the `SecurePreferences` object just once and reusing that object?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna try https://prashantsolanki3.github.io/Secure-Pref-Manager/ for easy and secure shared preferences.
You can use the given AES encryption or implement your own encryption algorithm.

Sample Code to Add a new Preference:

```
SecurePrefManager.with(this)
            .set("user_name")
            .value("LoremIpsum")
            .go();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own algorithm for security

I have this class

```
public class AESEncryption {
private static final int KEY_SIZE = 128;

private static final String KEY_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "AES";

private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

public static final byte[] iv = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

private static SecretKey getSecretKey(Context context) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String secretKeyString = PreferenceUtils.getSharedPreferences(context).getString(PreferenceUtils.SECRET_KEY, null);
    if (secretKeyString != null) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(secretKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return new SecretKeySpec(bytes, AESEncryption.KEY_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM);
    } else {
        SecretKey secretKey = newSecretKey();
        secretKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        PreferenceUtils.getSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString(PreferenceUtils.SECRET_KEY, secretKeyString).commit();

        return secretKey;
    }
}

private static SecretKey newSecretKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM);
    keyGenerator.init(KEY_SIZE);
    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}

public static String encrypt(Context context, String data) {
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(context);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] transformedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());

        return Base64.encodeToString(transformedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
        return data;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(BadPaddingException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        return data;
    }
}

public static String decrypt(Context context, String data) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        bytes = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return data;
    }

    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(context);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes));
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        return data;
    } catch(NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(BadPaddingException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(InvalidKeyException e) {
        return data;
    } catch(InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

}

then after when we save or get data from shared preference we simply use below
//get data

```
 public static String getUser(Context context) {
    String encryptedUser = getSharedPreferences(context).getString(USERNAME, null);
    return encryptedUser != null ? AESEncryption.decrypt(context, encryptedUser) : null;
}
```

//save data

```
public static void setLoginUser(Context context, String user, String password, String nickname) {
    String encryptedUser = AESEncryption.encrypt(context, user);
    String encryptedPassword = AESEncryption.encrypt(context, password);
    getSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString(USERNAME, encryptedUser).putString(PASSWORD, encryptedPassword)
            .putString(NICKNAME, nickname).commit();
}
```

you may change your own key or logic foe algo.

thank you

Comment: *you may change your own key or logic for algo.

thank you